# php truncate using grep preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match, truncate

The aim is to truncate a chat log to maximum 100 lines (when each new line is added), by reading the file from disk into a string (appending \n\n), then using a truncate function to preg_match a pattern of up to 100 lines and return the first instance of that match, then writing the match to the file.

This all works without the truncate function. The preg_match pattern selects correctly in a TextWrangler file. But adding the truncate function as shown results in erasing the whole text.

```
$existing= file_get_contents('LOG.txt') ;
// get new text-line $addnew from POST 
$addnew=$addnew."\n\n";
$newlog = $addnew.$existing ;
$newlog = truncate ( $newlog ) ;
file_put_contents('LOG.txt',$newlog);

function truncate ( $string ) {
    preg_match('#^[(.*?)\n\n]{0,100}#',$string,$match);
    if ( isset ($match[0] ) ) {
        $string=$match[0];
    }
    return  $string  ;
}
```

What does this need? Thank you.

Comment: Don't use character class, use instead: `^(.*?\n\n){0,100}`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: What does this have to do with the UNIX tool `grep`? If the answer is nothing, as it seems to be, then please [edit] your question to remove that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^[(.*?)\n\n]{0,100}` is a character class that means 0 to 100 any of `(` or `.` or `*` or `?` or `)` or `\n`.

I guess you want :

```
preg_match('#^(.*?\n\n){0,100}#',$string,$match)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.